# Google Play does not show the "Update" feature when I have already manually installed an older version of apk

Tags: android, google-play, android-version

I have installed an old version (4.0) of my application manually. In Google Play store I have already uploaded a new app with the same package name and incremented the app version to version 5.0. But Google Play store does not show the "Update" button.

This will only occur when the old app is installed manually.It will show the "Update" function on Google Play store.

Comment: how did you install it manually?

Comment: this sentence is a contradiction "This will only occur when old app installed via manually.When old app installed via manually this problem will not occur."

Comment: Do both apps have the same package name and are signed by the same private key/certificate?

Comment: Did you installed signed version yourself or something else like debug version?

Comment: @kAvEh it was a singed version.

Comment: its so weird. if you signed it with same key as you uploaded in google play and also package ID is the same, it must show you the update. I tried it so many times and it worked for me.

Comment: did you test it with another device and see the update? google play updates are gradually and may take up to 24 hours.

Answer (score 2):

The update dialog will only show if all of the following are true:

- The current user has already installed the app once (on any device), that is, it is in the User's library. This can be checked in the Ply store app by looking in the "My apps and games" menu under "Library"
- The package name (application id) for the app is the same
- the app is signed with the same key as the the app is published with on the Play store. In the case of Apps enrolled into Google Play app signing, this has to be the Play store key, not the upload key